# Swift class doesn't conform to objective c protocol inherited from swift protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am having an issue checking for objective-c protocol conformance when it is inherited from a swift protocol.
As far as I understand the following code should print true.
(Swift 3)

```
import UIKit

protocol MyProtocol: UITableViewDelegate {}

class MyClass: UIViewController, MyProtocol {}

let myClass = MyClass()

print(myClass.conforms(to: UITableViewDelegate.self))
// prints false 

let viewController = myClass as UIViewController
print(viewController as? UITableViewDelegate ?? "not a delegate")
// prints not a delegate
```

If anyone knows why this is happening or how to properly check this conformance that'd be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3, adding `@objc` to my `MyProtocol` works.

Comment: Awesome thanks, it appears this is a swift 3.1 Xcode 8.3.X issue

Answer (score 1):

Why it's **true** for me(tested with Swift 3.2 and 4.0), did we really do the same thing:

[image]

Comment: Yep I was doing the same thing, you are right this is fixed for 3.2 & 4. I was using swift 3.1

Comment: So that. Thanks for figuring it out!